# Прилипающий к ссылкам курсор (подвижные ссылки)

Tags: javascript, курсор

Как реализовать такой курсор, как на [этом](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/andra-photography-portfolio-wordpress-ajax-theme/full_screen_preview/21910095?ref=cirvitis&clickthrough_id&redirect_back=true) сайте?

За курсором круг (меняет свои свойства на разных элементах) и самое главное курсор как бы прилипает к ссылкам и тянет их за собой.

Покапавшись в консоли заметил, что вроде библиотека `tweenmax.min.js` отвечает за это (но крайне не уверен)

Comment: Нет доступа на сайт.

Comment: "TweenMax is the most feature-packed (and popular) animation tool in the GSAP arsenal" © у вас еще сомнения есть, что это она?

Comment: Так это кастомизированное готовое решение? Или нужно писать такую вещь с нуля? Просто уже встретил около 5 сайтов именно с таким курсором